# Restore pg_dump with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pg-dump

i'm trying to restore a pg_dump with pgAdmin 4.

this is the command i've used to create the backup `pg_dump -U {dbUser} -h localhost -Fc {dbName} > {backupFolder}/{backupName}`, but when i try to restore it using pgAdmin i get this:

[image]

If i execute the command pg_restore manually i get this error

> pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file

I've created the dump on a linux machine and trying to restore it with pgAdmin from a windows machine to the linux machine

any help? thanks!

Comment: Restore the dump with `pg_restore` on the command line. That's what pgAdmin does internally, and that way you see the error messages.

Comment: Or upgrade pgAdmin's bug fix release, as not showing the error message is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: It seems like your backup is corrupt.  Or missing.  Has is size been truncated to zero?  And "SQL" is an unintuitive suffix to use on a -Fc dump.

Comment: the dump i create with pg_dump on the linux machine is actually a little bit bigger (11KB) than the one i create with pgAdmin from windows (8KB)... the one from windows works, but the one from linux gives me that error...

Comment: I don't know of a general problem restoring based on OS where the pg_restore program runs, so whatever the details are it still looks like some kind of file corruption.  What versions are in use on each server?  If you transport the 11kb file back to Linux, does pg_restore then work?  You can use `pg_restore -f - dump_file.dmp > /dev/null` if you want to test the file without actually doing anything to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually the ftp method i was using to transfer the dump... The file was a bit bigger after the ftp transfer, fixing the ftp transfer have solved the problem!